# Simplifying complexity in for a table object structure

Tags: c#

I have an object structure that is mimicking the properties of an excel table. So i have a table object containing properties such as title, header row object and body row objects. Within the header row and each body row object, i have a cell object containing info on each cell per row. I am looking for a more efficient way to store this table structure since in one of my uses for this object, i am printing its structure to screen. Currently, i am doing an O(n^2) complexity for printing each row for each cell:

```
foreach(var row in Table.Rows){
   foreach(var cell in row.Cells){
      Console.WriteLine(cell.ToString())
   }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of storing this structure to avoid the n^2? I ask this because this printing functionality exists in another n^2 loop. Basically i have a list of tables titles and a list of tables. I need to find those tables whose titles are in the title list. Then for each of those tables, i need to print their rows and the cells in each row. Can any part of this operation be optimized by using a different data structure for storage perhaps? Im not sure how exactly they work but i have heard of hashing and dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to print out a table with n columns and n rows then you are printing out n^2 items so n^2 time is inevitable. Or is your data sparse such that you might only have data to print in a small portion of those cells?

Comment: You can optimize the storage in certain cases, but you will not be able to optimize the printing.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh: Pot-ay-to, po-tah-to in this case. Whether he iterates through each cell of N columns in M rows in two dimensions, or iterates through a one-dimensional collection of M*N items, he's still referencing the same number of items. In this case, with a table of cells, when you add a row you add as many cells as there are columns, and similarly with adding a column. You very rarely have constructs you call "tables" where the number of cells among each row or column differs. So, we generally refer to tabular data in N^2 terms based on row count.

Comment: I prefer to think that Columns count is constant, so a table will grow only in one dimention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for tables with specific titles, you could use a dictionary to store the tables by title

```
Dictionary<string,Table> tablesByTitle = new Dictionary<string,Table>();

tablesByTitle.Add(table.Title, table);
...

table = tablesByTitle["SomeTableTitle"];
```

This would make finding a table an O(1) operation. Finding `n` tables would be an O(n) operation.

Printing the tables then of cause depends on the number of rows and columns. There is nothing, which can change that.

---

UPDATE:

```
string tablesFromGuiElement = "Employees;Companies;Addresses";
string[] selectedTables = tablesFromGuiElement.Split(';');
foreach (string title in selectedTables) {
    Table tbl = tablesByTitle[title];
    PrintTable(tbl);
}
```

Comment: How will i add a dictionary entry in the first place? I mean right now i have two lists, one for names and one for tables. How do i add a matchning entry to the dictionary? Wouldnt i first have to find which table matches which table title? Wouldnt this defeat the purpose of having a dictionary as im still iterating both lists in n^2 time to find the matching title to the table in order to add to the dict?

Comment: If you store the titles in your table class, there is no point in storing the titles in a separate list. You could drop the titles list and the tables list completely. If, for some reason, you need to keep the tables list you can do that. Override `ToString()` in the tables class to return the table title. If you want to display a list of titles in a ComboBox for example, you can just add table objects to the ComboBox and it will display the titles automatically. The SelectedItem will be a table instead of just a table title.

Comment: The seperate list of titles comes from a gui element. The user selects which tables to see based on text entry. Then those comma seperated table titles are built into a list upon execution of the Show Tables button. I am then to look for those tables to print in my list of tables

Comment: If you add the tables to the dictionary at the same time you add them to the list, no additional lookup is required.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything more efficient than an N^2 operation for outputting an NxN matrix of values. Worst-case, you will always be doing this.

Now, if instead of storing the values in a multidimensional collection that defines the graphical relationship of rows and columns, you put them in a one-dimensional collection and included the row-column information with each cell, then you would only need to iterate through the cells that had values. Worst-case is still N^2 for a table of N rows and N columns that is fully populated (the one-dimensional array, though linear to enumerate, will have N^2 items), but the best case would be that only one cell in that table is populated (or none are) which would be constant-time.

Comment: same difference but harder to lookup, I go along with the first paragraph.

Comment: You can make the assumption that all tables are completely full

Answer (score 0):

**This answer applies to the, printing the table part, but the question was extended.**

for the getting the table part, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669817/659190).

---

No, there is not.

Unless perhaps your values follow some predictable distribution, then you could use a function of x and y and store no data at all, or maybe a seed  and a function.

You could cache the print output in a string or StringBuider if you require it multiple times.

If there is enough data I guess you might apply some compression algorithm but I wouldn't say that was simpler or more efficient.